# Dents appearing in render

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, error, screw-modifier

The mesh seems alright but there are dents in render view; the mesh was created using modifiers (screw over a circle to create a spring):

[image]

[image]

What I tried:

- recalculate normals for whole mesh
- recalculate normals for selected face
- dissolve/recreate face

Comment: as I said about your previous question, you should create a UV map dedicated to the text part (a second UV map). Here the UV map you have projects overlapping things over non text parts.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to fix it (was too tired Yesterday)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section you have highlighted is caused by the material on the object. Either remove the material, or move the affected sections away from the "text" in the UV map.

[image: Dents1]

The section further down that looks improper is because of flipped normals. Select the whole mesh in edit mode and then select *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*.

[image: Dents2]

[image: Dents3]

After recalculation:

[image: Dents4]

Comment: Thanks! The material for the spring was off (also had the normal applied over it).